# Rewrite rule fir NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm pretty bad in reg expression and nginx rewrite rules. 
I need help to figure rewrite rules for the following situation for NGINX.

```
http://example.com/blog/category1/postname => http://example.com/category1/postname
http://example.com/blog/category1/helloworld => http://example.com/category1/helloworld
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one is pretty simple, you just want to tell nginx to ignore the word blog ( and I'll assume it has to be followed with the word `category1` )

```
rewrite ^/category1/(.*) /blog/category1/$1 last;
#       |      |      |     |            |    |
#      [1]    [2]    [3]   [4]          [5]  [6]
```

[1]: URL begins with 
[2]: category1 
[3]: capture all that follows 
[4]: add `blog` 
[5]: add the rest of the URL ( that we captured in [3] ) 
[6]: stop the rewrite and process the new URL and any other matching rewrites.